# htaccess 301 redirect and rewrite urls

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I just moved a site and some of the old pages are still being viewed. Here is an example of the old url structure:

```
http://mydomain.com/text_version/personal_and_people_development.php
```

And how I want it to redirect to:

```
http://mydomain.com/personal-and-people-development/
```

What I want it to do is 301 redirect any page in the folder `/text_version/` by stripping the `/text_version` piece of the path, convert all underscores to hyphens and replace the `.php` file extension with a trailing slash.

Also note I allow the user to use the `www.` subdomain, and may require `https://` access in future.

Is it possible to do a folder wide 301 redirect like so or do I have to specify each individual page? If so can someone give me a pointer as I am not very good with `mod_rewrite` or `regex`.

**Update:** This is what I have managed to piece together so far due to stringing together other people's code. This is stored in a `.htaccess` file located in the `/text_version` subfolder.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L, QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteRule (.*)_(.*) $1-$2 [N]
```

However this converts:

```
http://mydomain.com/text_version/personal_and_people_development.php
```

to

```
http://mydomain.com/personal-and-people-development.php/
```

Comment: @faa I didn't have that code at the time of posting. But now I have sussed that.

Comment: Glad you found out the way to do it. That's why I deleted my previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of messing about, and not understanding most of it I managed to piece together this solution:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (.*)_(.*) $1-$2 [N]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ .*\.php.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php(.*)?$ /$1$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ^(www.)?mydomain.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I am not sure the last 2 lines work. This part `^(www.)?mydomain.com/$1/` is not a regex and is sent literally as part of the substitution URL. On the other hand, the incoming URL can't have any path according to this `!(.*)/$` and therefore the back reference $1 is capturing an empty string. I think you should test those lines. You can do it [here](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)

Comment: @faa strange behaviour at that site but works in my browser, chrome +ie8

Comment: @faa that tester doesn't support `%{THE_REQUEST}`